# Documentation for Hugo syntax inside of handlebars?

Tags: go, hugo

I'm trying to build a site with Hugo and having a hard time understanding some of their documentation. Specifically, when displaying frontmatter in a template.

There are functions you can preform on variables inside the handle bars. ex: {{ range .Data.Pages }} What is range? I can't find any documentation on what these functions do. Or is it just plain Go code and anything Go is fair game? Just looking for documentation so I can figure out what I need.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is here: https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/

Comment: @JimB This is helpful, thank you

Comment: @asebold do you need to do something specific with frontmatter fields (iterate or sort them for example) or do you just simply want to have extra custom fields in each .md?

Comment: @revelt it looks like we're going to go with custom fields.

Comment: It depends what flavour of front matter you prefer, but it's simple, declare variable in article's `.md` file, like `video: "your_url'`, then reference it anywhere within the ranged partial: `{{ if .Params.video }}{{ .Params.video }}{{ end }}`. Is this what you're looking for specifically?

Answer (score 0):

These are functions that have specifically been made available to Go templates (you can't just use any Go functions). They include the built-in functions documented in the [golang.org template docs](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) which JimB linked to in his comment, and also Hugo-specific functions which are documented on the [Hugo template functions page](https://gohugo.io/templates/functions/).